# Transfer a form name containing an id to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want js to get the fields of a form, located in a modal. The id of my modal is set this way: `th:id="myModal+${employee.id}"`.
And the id of my form, this way: `<form th:id="update+${employee.id}" class="form-horizontal" role="form">`. I want this form id to be recuperated in my js and what I have done will not work.

I have posted both my modal and JS code below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-target='#myModal'+${employee.id}">
    Update Modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" th:id="myModal+${employee.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            <form th:id="update+${employee.id}" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
                    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${employee.id}" id="id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">                
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" id="update" th:onclick="'javascript:updateEmp();'" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function updateEmp() {
    var location = "http://localhost:8080/update";
    console.log($("#update+id"));
    var employeeForm = $("#update+id").serializeJSON();
    console.log(employeeForm);
    var employeeData = JSON.stringify(employeeForm);
    console.log(employeeData);
    $.ajax({
        url: location,
        type: 'POST',
        data: employeeData, //not included for GET
        //dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (results) {}
```

And I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: `var data = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: Change 
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" id="update" th:onclick="'javascript:updateEmp(${employee.id});'" />
AND
function updateEmp(id) {
$("#update"+id).serializeJSON();
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, bind event using it. You can add a CSS class and the bind event using `Class Selector $('.class')`

*HTML*

```
<input type="button" 
       class="btn btn-default updateButton" 
       value="Update"  />
```

*Script*

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".updateButton", function(){
        //Get form ans serialize it
        var employeeForm = $(this).closest('form').serializeJSON();

        //Rest of the code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" id="update" th:onclick="'javascript:updateEmp(this);'" />
```

JS

```
function updateEmp(button) {
    $.ajax({
        url: location,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(button).parent('form').serialize(), //not included for GET
        //dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (results) {}

    })
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution.  However, it does not receive the fields of the form. When I do var updateData=JSON.stringify(data); and display it, it shows an empty object.  So nothing is sent to my controller and I get this error message: POST http://localhost:8080/update 400 (Bad Request).  Any idea how to bypass this?